# How Does Odoo Handle Database Locking?

Tags: database, postgresql, locking, odoo

I know Odoo will not concurrently update a table row. However my understanding is that two people can be looking at the same record simultaneously in edit mode. When both users save the record is overwritten by whoever saved last (even if 1ms later). However this could mean that a user is updating the record based on data which may have in fact changed while they were editing the exact same record.

How can row level locking be enforced in Odoo?

How can you restrict a record from being opened in edit mode if someone else has the same record opened in edit mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odoo doesn't have such functionality. You can write your own but it will be complicated.

In general. You can create table/model with Locks. 
For example when user clicks edit button You could create lock in Locks table and when another user clicks edit on that document it will read table with locks. If there is a lock, exception pop out.

When user who created lock will save changes or on timeout, lock should be released but user waiting for his turn should only be able to save changes after reloading the page.

It's simple concept but general it's not easy to do.

Odoo is not meant by itself for colaboration of many users on one shared document. There are addons working with etherpad like in notes. **You can use etherpad in critical fields of models which must be shared among several users at once.**